# Extend Java abstract class in Scala

Tags: java, scala, abstract-class

Given a Java class, something like

```java
public abstract class A {
    public A(URI u) {
    }
}
```

I can extend it in Scala like this

```scala
class B(u: URI) extends A(u) { }
```

However, what I would like to do is alter the constructor of B, something like

```scala
case class Settings()

class B(settings: Settings) extends A {
  // Handle settings
  // Call A's constructor
}
```

What's the correct syntax for doing this in Scala?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363381/how-to-extend-an-abstract-class-in-scala-and-use-the-abstract-constructor

Comment: @jmizv thanks, I did see that but I don't think it helps, as I can't change the Java class.

Comment: You can ass an overload constructor in `B` or put that logic in an `apply` of the companion object. Also, you can make the primary constructor of `B` **private** to ensure users always use the alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Blocks are expressions in Scala, so you can run code before calling the superclass constructor. Here's a (silly) example:

```scala
class Foo(a: Int)
class Bar(s: String) extends Foo({
  println(s)
  s.toInt
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that in a very similar way to [Object inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64713535/2359227) with early initializer.

Assuming there is an abstract class `A` as declared above, you can do:

```scala
case class Settings(u: URI)

class B(s: Settings) extends {
  val uri = s.u
} with A(uri)
```

Then call:

```scala
val b = new B(Settings(new URI("aaa")))
println(b.uri)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java ["Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) so, you can't really handle settings before calling A's c'tor. Even if it doesn't look like this all the initialization inside of class definition are actually constructors code. That's why there is no syntax for calling super's c'tor