# Passing Parameters Made in a Case Class to a Trait

Tags: scala, testing

**Context**

For the sake of being able to change the config for testing, I have a trait with almost all the code. Then in a case class I am trying to pass in the config. In my testing I have a testing case class.

**This works (but is not the funcionality I want)**

```
trait Greeting(val name: String) {
  def msg = s"How are you, $name"
}

class prodEnvClass extends Greeting("Production Env") {
  println(msg)
}

class testEnvClass extends Greeting("Testing Env") {
  println(msg)
}
```

**This does not work (but is the functionality I want)**

```
trait Greeting(val name: String) {
  def msg = s"How are you, $name"
}

class prodEnvClass extends Greeting(myEnv) {
  val myEnv = fetchProdEnv()
  println(msg)
}

class testEnvClass extends Greeting(myEnv) {
  val myEnv = fetchTestEnv()
  println(msg)
}
```

**Question**

How do I pass a parameter made inside the case class body into the trait? The code that works does not match my use case. I want to use code inside the case class to make the input to the trait.

Comment: You can't AFAIK. (I also don't see a `case class` in your code btw). How would you initialize this? You need to initialize the trait to initialize the class but you also need to initialize the class to initialize the trait ? There is a conflict right there. You should make the class final and have a companion object initialize the class as needed. It can load the required config and pass it along. You can use [ciris](https://cir.is/) to load in the corresponding environments

Comment: Although I should note, you could have the method take the name as a parameter. That is the simple solution but that's not how I would design this

Comment: There is a similar post that needs the same functionality for a different purpose: [Extend Java abstract class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65276291/2359227)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be mixing function invocation with inheritance in a way that is not supposed to work.

For function invocation, you

- create binders as a function *parameters*, and then
- pass values as *arguments*,

something like this:

```
def f(s: String) { println(s) }
f("hello (function invocation)")
```

When using inheritance, you

- create binders by *naming abstract members*, and later you
- pass values by *providing implementations* for those abstract members

something like this:

```
trait C { def s: String; def m() = println(s) }
new C { val s = "hello (inheritance)"; m() }
```

In your code, you seem to attempt to

- bind the value as constructor *parameter* (as you would do for functions)
- pass the value `myEnv` by overriding it differently in two subclasses (as you would do for inheritance)

Just pick one mechanism. If you want inheritance, then do inheritance:

```
class MyEnv(val name: String)

trait Greeting {
  def myEnv: MyEnv
  def msg = s"hello ${myEnv.name}"
}

def fetchProdEnv() = new MyEnv("prod")
def fetchTestEnv() = new MyEnv("test")

class ProdEnvClass extends Greeting {
  val myEnv = fetchProdEnv()
  println(msg)
}

class TestEnvClass extends Greeting {
  val myEnv = fetchTestEnv()
  println(msg)
}

new ProdEnvClass() // "hello prod"
new TestEnvClass() // "hello test"
```

but don't try to use two halves (one half from each mechanism), they don't mix this way.